# Optimise mysql query with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, innodb

I have an InnoDB table with 11 columns and around 5 million records in which I am using a query to find the top 10 records with the highest sum. The table schema is as below.

```
id (int 11) (primary key)
activity_id(varchar 250)
activity_type (varchar 10)
advertised_time (timestamp)
advertised_train_ident(int 11)
technical_train_ident(int 11)
location_signature(varchar 10)
time_at_location(timestamp)
information_owner(varchar 100)
created_at(timestamp)
updated_at(timestamp)
```

The indexes present in the table are

```
id - primary key
location_signature,activity_type, advertised_time - composite index (name is search)
```

I am using the following query to pull records from the above table and it takes 10-12 seconds to complete the execution.

```
SELECT location_signature, activity_type,  
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) > 0 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) else 0 END) as delay_time, 
count(id) as total_train_count, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as delayed_train_count 
from `train_announcements` 
where `advertised_time` >= '2019-04-01 10:00:00' and `advertised_time` <= '2019-04-30 10:00:00' 
group by `location_signature`, `activity_type` 
order by `delay_time` desc 
limit 10 offset 0;
```

The Explain statement of this query is as follows

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | train_announcements        | index | search        | search  | 84      | NULL | 4910024| Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Please note that the collation of this table is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` because of the field location_signature contains special characters.

It would be great if someone can suggest any workarounds to improve the performance of this query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's more useful to provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.

Comment: I cannot group by id because it does not serve my purpose @RaymondNijland

Comment: Indeed never mind mine comment ive readed the query wrong for some reason

Comment: The other suggestion would be to try a deliverd table (subquery in the FROM) clause) where you filter the needed records before grouping, aggregates and reverse sorting.. In some MySQL optimizers it can make a difference

Comment: Did you really intend to have a date range of (1 month - 1 day + 1 second)?

Comment: What place has 5 million trains in a month?

Answer (score 3):

Looking to your index  be sure  you have  advertised_time   at top left

and could be useful  add also the time_at_location foe avoid access to data table and use data from index

index for table train_announcements

columns  (advertised_time, location_signature,activity_type, time_at_location)

```
SELECT location_signature
  , activity_type
  , SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) > 0 
            THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) 
            ELSE 0 END) as delay_time
  , count(id) as total_train_count
  , SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) > 0 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END) as delayed_train_count 
from `train_announcements` 
where `advertised_time` BETWEEN '2019-04-01 10:00:00' and '2019-04-30 10:00:00' 
group by `location_signature`, `activity_type` 
order by `delay_time` desc 
limit 10 offset 0;
```

and if you have not  id with null value the try using count(*) instead of count(id)

```
SELECT location_signature
  , activity_type
  , SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) > 0 
            THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) 
            ELSE 0 END) as delay_time
  , count(*) as total_train_count
  , SUM(CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,advertised_time, time_at_location) > 0 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END) as delayed_train_count 
from `train_announcements` 
where `advertised_time` BETWEEN '2019-04-01 10:00:00' and '2019-04-30 10:00:00' 
group by `location_signature`, `activity_type` 
order by `delay_time` desc 
limit 10 offset 0;
```

or if you really need  id too try add this column to the composite index

```
      (advertised_time, location_signature, activity_type, time_at_location, id )
```

Comment: When added the changes as you mentioned it improved the execution time to 7 seconds but, it isn't enough @scaisEdge

Comment: Try adding `delay_time` into the index as well. I've read somewhere before that when your `Explain` shows `using filesort`, its extra work. But I found this link https://www.slideshare.net/matsunobu/more-mastering-the-art-of-indexing , look at page 41 and it explain something similar.

Comment: .. then  your problem is not related only to the query  .. but also at you system  (memory size, disk type,  cpu) .. ad db arch.(db engine type  and table partition  ) ...    ..   .. for the query code   (by my experience  .. then so little can be done  .. )

Comment: @tcadidot0   delay_time  is a column alias  can't e added  to an index

Comment: @tcadidot0 delay_time is not a column present in the table and hence it cannot be added into the index

Comment: bummer @scaisEdge ! I didn't see that!

Comment: Ok2 my bad.. but I think you should take a look at the slides, it may help you in some way @Deepu

Comment: could be i already know the slide content  ..  ( and db  tuning  .. mastering  )  ...anyway thanks for suggestion  there is always something to learn

Comment: @Deepu  are yo usure you have change columns position and added time_at_location at the right end??  .. the reduction of 60% reduction seems to me little

Comment: Yes @scaisEdge. This is the index now advertised_time, location_signature, activity_type, time_at_location

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestion but, I have already tried that and it didn't make much difference to the time @scaisEdge

Comment: at least the time has shrunk by half does not seem to me little .. for a post on SO

Comment: It does a considerable difference but still, waiting for 7 seconds to complete only the query execution seems to be a problem for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193181/discussion-between-deepu-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @Deepu . . . I would expect the recommended index (with four keys) to have a larger impact on performance.  How many of the rows in the table match the `where` condition?

Answer (score 1):

Build and maintain a Summary table.  It would have subtotals for, say, each day.  Then the 'report' would be against this much smaller table, hence would be much faster.

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: It would be impossible because summarising the records for each date makes it not possible to search with a date and time interval

Comment: @Deepu - It might be worth summarizing each hour's data.  Is that a fine enough granularity?